# Template argument cannot be deduced

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to use `std::transform` to merge two equal size vectors into a vector of pairs.

```
int main()
{
    vector<string> names;
    // fill it with names    
    vector<int> nums;
    // fill it with numbers

    typedef pair<int,string> Pair_t;
    vector<Pair_t> pv;

    transform(nums.begin(), nums.end(),
              names.begin(), back_inserter(pv),
              make_pair<int,string>);
}
```

VC10 gives me:

```
'_OutIt std::transform(_InIt1,_InIt1,_InIt2,_OutIt,_Fn2)' : could not deduce template argument for '_OutIt' from 'std::back_insert_iterator<_Container>'
          with
          [
              _Container=std::vector<Pair_t>
          ]
```

So why can't the template argument be deduced?  And how do I fix it?

Comment: Compiles OK for me on GCC 4.4.3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is due to a bug in the current version of VC10 whereby the overload of `make_pair` cannot be resolved properly.

There is a discussion about this exact problem [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vclanguage/thread/bab04536-8a8d-4b5e-9a49-e10144688667/), along with a workaround using a C++0x lambda expression, which is supported by VC10.

Comment: Specifically, the issue is that in VC++ 2010 `std::make_pair` is overloaded for `(T1 const&, T2 const&)`, `(T1&&, T2 const&)`, `(T1 const&, T2&&)`, and `(T1&&, T2&&)`, whereas the *current* standard only calls for `(T1&&, T2&&)` which then forwards appropriately. Consequently, explicitly specifying the types of `T1` and `T2` does not sufficiently narrow down the available overloads to a single candidate.