# Filling std::map with std::transform (error: cannot deduce argument)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stl, c++11, visual-c++-2010

I'm trying to fill std::map with std::transform. Next code compiles without error:

```
std::set<std::wstring> in; // "in" is filled with data
std::map<std::wstring, unsigned> out;

std::transform(in.begin(), in.end()
,   boost::counting_iterator<unsigned>(0)
,   std::inserter(out, out.end())
,   [] (std::wstring _str, unsigned _val) { return std::make_pair(_str, _val); }
);
```

But If I replace string

```
,   [] (std::wstring _str, unsigned _val) { return std::make_pair(_str, _val); }
```

with

```
,   std::make_pair<std::wstring, unsigned>
```

or

```
,   std::ptr_fun(std::make_pair<std::wstring, unsigned>)
```

I get errors:

```
foo.cpp(327): error C2784: '_OutTy *std::transform(_InIt1,_InIt1,_InTy (&)[_InSize],_OutTy (&)[_OutSize],_Fn2)' : could not deduce template argument for '_InTy (&)[_InSize]' from 'boost::counting_iterator<Incrementable>'
      with
      [
          Incrementable=unsigned int
      ]
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\algorithm(1293) : see declaration of 'std::transform'
foo.cpp(327): error C2784: '_OutTy *std::transform(_InIt1,_InIt1,_InIt2,_OutTy (&)[_OutSize],_Fn2)' : could not deduce template argument for '_OutTy (&)[_OutSize]' from 'std::insert_iterator<_Container>'
      with
      [
          _Container=std::map<std::wstring,unsigned int>
      ]
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\algorithm(1279) : see declaration of 'std::transform'
foo.cpp(327): error C2784: '_OutIt std::transform(_InIt1,_InIt1,_InTy (&)[_InSize],_OutIt,_Fn2)' : could not deduce template argument for '_InTy (&)[_InSize]' from 'boost::counting_iterator<Incrementable>'
      with
      [
          Incrementable=unsigned int
      ]
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\algorithm(1267) : see declaration of 'std::transform'
foo.cpp(327): error C2914: 'std::transform' : cannot deduce template argument as function argument is ambiguous
```

and so on...
Please explain what is the problem is with compilation?

**UPDATE:** Thanks for answers. I realized, that it is MSVC2010 bug. By the way the line

```
&std::make_pair<const std::wstring&, const unsigned&>
```

causes the same error

Comment: possible duplicate of [Template argument cannot be deduced.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5864171/636019)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a bug in the Visual C++ library implementation.  The following program demonstrates the issue:

```
#include <utility>

int main()
{
    &std::make_pair<int, int>;
};
```

This program yields the error:

```
error C2568: 'identifier' : unable to resolve function overload
```

In the C++ language specification, `make_pair` is not an overloaded function.  The Visual C++ 2010 library implementation includes four overloads taking various combinations of lvalue and rvalue references.

While an implementation of the C++ Standard Library is allowed to add overloads for member functions, it isn't allowed to add overloads for nonmember functions, thus this is a bug.

The bug [was reported and will be fixed in the next version of Visual C++](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/606746/incorrect-overload-resolution).  However, as STL notes in the resolution to that bug, you'll need to make the template arguments to `std::make_pair` lvalue references:

```
&std::make_pair<const std::wstring&, const unsigned&>
```

Answer (score 3):

g++ 4.4.5 compiles it without errors.  Seems to be a [Visual Studio 10 defect](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vclanguage/thread/bab04536-8a8d-4b5e-9a49-e10144688667/).